# Calling a polymer function on onchange event in input tag

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, onchange

This is my demo code

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    console.log('this workes');     
  }
</script>

<dom-module id="element-a">
  <template>
   <div style="text-align: center;">
    <label for="fileinput" class="custom-file-upload">Change Picture</label>
    <input id="fileinput" type="file" onchange="myFunction()"/>
   </div>  
  </template>

<script>
 Polymer({
  is: 'element-a',

   myPolymerFunction: function(){
      console.log('success')
   }
 });
</script> 
</dom-module>
```

In the above code when ever I select a new picture the `onchange` event will be trigered and it will call `myFunction()`. How do I call a polymer function in the same way?

When I replace `onchange` with `myPolymerFunction` it gives the following error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: myPolymerFunction is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use "()" when binding a polymer function.
2. "onchange" should be "on-change"

   ```
   <dom-module id="my-element">

     <template>
       <input id="fileinput" type="file" on-change="hello"/>
     </template>

     <script>
       class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
         static get is() { return 'my-element'; }

         hello(evt) {
           console.log(evt);
         }
       }
       window.customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
     </script>

   </dom-module>
   ```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/rixibucepa/edit?html,console,output